# Web service axis fault: Error in deserializing body of request message

Tags: web-services

I am calling a webservice in java using basic auth. My code is deployed in an environment and in logs I can see this error as Axis Fault "Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetUser'." 
I am not able to debug it right now due to some environment issues so can anyone please give me some hint on when we get such type of errors?

Comment: your request post data might have large size. This can be cause axis fault

Comment: It seems that you have a mismatch of the parameters of `GetUser` between client and server.